# GridView, how to get key of current row?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I get currently selected row key from ASP.NET `GridView` control?
If I handle `SelectedIndexChanged` event, it is not raised on paging nor sorting, even if selected record id is changed.
If I handle `Sorted` event or `PageIndexChanged`, there is only `null` value in `GridView.SelectedValue`.

I need this for updating dynamically added controls depending on currently selected row.

**EDIT**

GridView markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID_USER" DataSourceID="dsUsers" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView_SelectedIndexChanging" 
    onpageindexchanged="GridView_PageIndexChanged" onsorted="GridView_Sorted">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: in which do you want to get selected row key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I handle Sorted event or PageIndexChanged, there is only null value
>   in GridView.SelectedValue.

Check for the SelectedValue in an event that is later in the control's life cyle.  Like PreRender:

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentValue = GridView1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Don't forget to add `OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender"` to your markup.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have some code in Page_PreRenderComplete, so I use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

user `DataKeyNames` property of the gridview.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID">
 </asp:GridView>
```

I usually pass the RowIndex via CommandArgument and use it to retrieve the DataKey value I want.

On the Button:

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'
```

On the Server Event

```
int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
string val = (string)this.grid.DataKeys[rowIndex]["ProductID"];
```

Comment: I mean currently selected row primary key value (not name).

Comment: You just add the `primary key column` in `DataKeyNames` and you can get it.

Comment: Is not a problem that GridView is bounded in markup (event comes later than paging event?)? I watch GridView.DataKeys and it is null on GridView_PageIndexChanged event.